# Bootstrap GridView Column show / hidding not working as per mobile / tab / desktop

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Small - 2]

[image: Large -1]

When I moving the screen as small, medium, large view, but it is not hiding / showing the column perfectly. In the Large view column should show all, hence here it is showing only **ID and Name** column and other view is the same.

Here is my Code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="mainContainer" class="container">
                <div class="shadowBox">
                    <div class="page-container">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="jumbotron">
                                <p class="text-danger">Responsive GridView in ASP.NET </p>
                                <span class="text-info">Desktop Tablet Phone Different layout </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="grdCustomer" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-xs" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-xs" />
                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" SortExpression="Salary" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-md" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-md" />
                                                <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden-xs" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden-xs" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden-xs" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden-xs" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" SortExpression="Region" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-md" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-md" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" SortExpression="PostalCode" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-md" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-md" />  
<asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-lg" />--%>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am requesting your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

To toggle content across viewport breakpoints using [Bootstrap responsive classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes), you have to use `.visible-x-y`, where:

- `x` is the screen *size* (i.e. `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`)
- `y` is the CSS `display` property value (i.e. `block`, `inline`, `inline-block`)

Your `HeaderStyle-CssClass` and `ItemStyle-CssClass` are missing the "`y` part".

Comment: Thanks for your promt response. I am following this wesite help: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/47548d/responsive-grid-view-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Still it is not working and I am using : visible-lg-block

Comment: Your web site gives .NET "Server Error in '/' Application".

Answer (score 0):

just add dot before visible-*. The code looks like

```
ItemStyle-CssClass=".visible-md-block" 
HeaderStyle-CssClass=".visible-md-block"
```